# How to vertically stack buttons in adaptive cards for MS teams in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I tried using Column Set with each column containing a button, But MS Teams doesn't render buttons in preferred format whereas webchat does.

[image]

[image]

In addition, I tried changing the size of "MIS Reports" button in MS Teams such that all buttons are of same size irrespective of the content, but I found there is no such property in adaptive cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try adding the buttons inside different columns in different columnsets? I have tried the below json and it worked for me:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                                    "title": "Action.Submit"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                                    "title": "Submit action 2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                                    "title": "Submit action3"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: @Gouisa-MSFT : Thanks a lot, It worked. Do you know by anyways we can have the all the buttons of same width? In your image button 2 is larger than others.

Comment: @ManishChitre Currently, there is no way to set width for buttons. They pick up the width based on the length of text.

Comment: This can be simplified by removing the ColumnSets and instead just having a list of ActionSets